# The floor function's relationship with odd and even functions

Tags: calculus, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

**Question**

Suppose $f: \Re \to \Re$ is a real valued function defined on the whole real line. For each a) and b) determine if the statement is correct and justify your answer.

a) If $f(x)$ is even then $g(x)= \left \lfloor{f(x)}\right \rfloor $ even.

b) If $f(x)$ is odd then $g(x)= \left \lfloor{f(x)}\right \rfloor $ odd.

---

> **Things I know**
>
> I know that the floor function is the greatest integer less than the
>   value x.
>
> $f(x)=f(-x)$ if $f(x)$ **is even** and the graphs are symmetrical
>   about y=0
>
> $f(x)=-f(-x)$ if $f(x)$ **is odd**

I have tried to think of a way, but with the knowledge I dont know how to come to the conclusion if the statements are correct and to justify. But my knowledge is up to date with the school syllabus (what we have been taught already). How do I do this?

Comment: No.how about $f(x)=\sin x$

Comment: @Booldy If $f(x)=\sin x$ then $f(x)$ is odd, and $g(x)$ is odd? So in that example its yes for b part.

Comment: In "Things I know" it should be $f(x)=-f(-x)$ if $f(x)$ **is odd**. Personally I think it's better to write $f(-x)=-f(x)$ if $f(x)$ **is odd** (and better right $f$ instead of $f(x)$ when talking about the function not the value of the image of $x$).

Comment: @Scientifica oh yes my bad :) Corrected it

Comment: M.S.E $g(x)$ i not odd for $f(x)=\sin x$

Comment: @Booldy why not?

Comment: @M.S.E Good job :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

b) is incorrect. The easiest counter example is taking $f(x)=x$. Booldy's counter example is correct too because if $f(x)=\sin x$ then $g(x)=\lfloor\sin (-x)\rfloor=\lfloor -\sin x\rfloor$ but nothing ensures that $\lfloor -\sin x\rfloor=-\lfloor \sin x\rfloor$. Take $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ to be convinced.

For a) just use the definition you have. Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$.$f$ is even so $f(-x)=f(x)$. Now use this while calculating $g(-x)$.

Comment: b) $x=\pi/2$ is one of the few points where $\lfloor-\sin x\rfloor=-\lfloor\sin x\rfloor$

Comment: @Michael totally out of topic: oh your from Adelaide, me too :D

Comment: Im reading your answer :)

Comment: :o my bad! I mean $\frac{\pi}{4}$ not $\frac{\pi}{2}$. So take this in consideration M.S.E. +1 Micheal

Comment: +1 Yippiee I understand part b.....but I am still not understanding part a.

Comment: Normally you shouldn't give +1 until you totally agree but thank you very much! :D For part a, if $x\in\mathbb{R}$, to prove that $g$ is even you should prove that $g(-x)=g(x)$. So under the assumption that $f$ is even, i.e $f(-x)=f(x)$, we have: $g(-x)=\lfloor f(-x)\rfloor$ right? But $f(-x)=f(x)$ so? Can you see now why $g(-x)=g(x)$?

Comment: @M.S.E off topic: I'm going to eat now I'll be back in some minutes...

Comment: @Scientifica off topic: Your Awesome :D

Comment: @M.S.E off topic: You're embarassing me ^^ xD I'm not :p but thank you!